# How to fill array in Python by rest values?

Tags: python

I have a full list: `f = [A,B,C,D,E]`.

And short list: `s = [A,B,D]`

I want to get result list as `short list` + `all rest values` from full list that there are not in short list.

**Result should be:**

```
nlist = [A,B,D,C,E]
```

I tried two loops:

```
let nlist = s
for f in full:
  for s in short:
     if s not in f:
         nlist.append(f)
```

But I think it is wrong way

Comment: If your nlist is everything from s plus everything from l that is not in s, isn't then your nlist inevitably going to contain the same items as your original l? (Not necessarily in the same order though, admittedly)

Comment: To be clear: for this input example, what should the result be?

Comment: Result should be `nlist = [A,B,D,C,E]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst = short_lst + [x for x in long_lst if x not in short_lst]
```

Comment: After that operation I got array but elements in short array is in another sequence, I have to safe them

Answer (score 0):

If the lists `f` and `s` do **not** contain dublicates (like in your example), it is also possible do the following,

```
f = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
s = ["A", "B", "D"]

s.extend(set(f) ^ set(s))
print(s) # output: ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'C']
```

where the `^` operator is the [symmetric difference operator](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/symmetric_difference). If you want to know the difference between the difference and symmetric difference, I recommend checking out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50871370/python-sets-difference-vs-symmetric-difference) question.
However, Timur's answer is probably the approach you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Method to **concatenate** the **unique values** from **multiple lists** of **different size** and **sort** them:

```
x = ['I','G','F','A']
y = ['H','E','B','J','B']
z = ['D','C','A']

nlist = sorted(set(x+y+z))
nlist

#output
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
```

Answer (score 0):

For huge *full_list* size try:

```
full_list = ['A','B','C','D','E']
short_list = ['A','B','D']

for i,s in enumerate(short_list):
    if s in full_list:
        full_list[full_list.index(s)] = full_list[i]
        full_list[i]=s
print(full_list)
```

Result

```
[A,B,D,C,E]
```

**Note**

- This method is slightly faster than others as you sort the full_list **inplace**.
- But it's less readable compared to other answers.